# Pass string from javascript popout box to input form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to click a button, type my url into a popout box and then automatically submit this new link into a form to update my database.

Javascript function:

```
function flickrFunction() {
    var x;
    var flickr =prompt("Please enter your Flickr URL","<?=$flickrLink?>");
    if (flickr!=null) {
      x = flickr;
      document.getElementById("fl").value = x;
    }
```

php/html

```
<?php } if(!empty($flickrLink)){ ?>
    <a><button onclick="flickrFunction()" style="width: 45px; height: 45px; border: none;">
       <img src="../images/social/fl.png" width="40" height="40"></button></a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a><button onclick="flickrFunction()" style="width: 45px; height: 45px; border: none;">
       <img src="../images/social/flAdd.png" width="40" height="40"></button></a>
<?php } ?>
```

html form

```
<form method="post" action="admin.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitSocial" value="true"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="fl" id="fl" value="<?=$flickrLink?>"
         onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
</form>
```

I just can't see where I'm going wrong with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any error showing up in the console? Note that the code you posted is missing a closing brace for the flickrFunction -- does your real code have the correct closing brace?

Comment: As Elias mentionned, you close the `if` conditionnal statement in the `flickrFunction()` function, but you do not close the function itself!

Comment: I think the onchange event doesn't work on hidden inputs, because those events are meant for user interaction, and hidden inputs don't have user interaction.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the function is closed in my code, just missed it off copying in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should submit the form after you change the value...

Also, Give a name to your form

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="admin.php">


// Script
...
document.getElementById("fl").value = x;
document.myform.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I knew it was something simple I was missing.